# filter method replacing one array with another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I'm trying to filter out the values of one array from another array.  When using Javascript's filter method, my script looks like this.

```
var notUsed = ["Advanced Tac. Training Area", "Dunbarton Railroad Yard"];

var areas = ["A Area", "Advanced Tac. Training Area", "B Area", "Dunbarton Railroad Yard", "C Area"];

areas.filter(function(){
    return areas = notUsed;
})
console.log(areas);
```

According to the documentation, when I console the `areas` array after I've run the filter function, the array should look like this

```
"A Area", "B Area", "C Area"
```

However, that's not what's happening.  Instead, I'm getting the values of the `notUsed` array, so it's essentially replacing the areas array with the `notUsed` array.  Can anyone explain why this is happening and how I go about getting the `areas` array without the values of the `notUsed` array?

If this question has already been asked, please let me know in the comments and link to the answered question.  that way I can delete this one and eliminate the duplication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two mistakes.

1. `areas = notUsed` will simply assign the value of `notUsed` to `areas`, it doesn't compare them.
2. `filter` returns a new array. It doesn't change the original array.

Probably you can write it like this

```
areas = areas.filter(function (area) {
  return notUsed.indexOf(area) === -1;
});
```

Now, the `notUsed.indexOf(area)` returns the index of the `area` in the `notUsed` array. If it couldn't find it, then it will return `-1`.

Also, see we assign the result of `filter` back to `areas`.

Comment: Awesome, thank you.  Do you know why this isn't something that's explained or demonstrated in the documentation?  I know that it explains that the original array is not changed, but it doesn't demonstrate how to do anything like this.  At least, not that I've seen.

Comment: @Robert There are [few examples in MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter#Examples).

Answer (score 0):

You have not understood the use of filter correctly.

```
var notUsed = ["Advanced Tac. Training Area", "Dunbarton Railroad Yard"];

var areas = ["A Area", "Advanced Tac. Training Area", "B Area", "Dunbarton Railroad Yard", "C Area"];

var res = areas.filter(function(ele){
    return (notUsed.indexOf(ele) == -1)
})
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

The Filter function should test the values in the array against a condition implemented by you. This is not the case in your example. [Filter Function](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

This could be a possible solution for you.

```js
var notUsed = ["Advanced Tac. Training Area", "Dunbarton Railroad Yard"];

var areas = ["A Area", "Advanced Tac. Training Area", "B Area", "Dunbarton Railroad Yard", "C Area"];

var filtered = areas.filter(value => { return notUsed.indexOf(value) === -1 })
console.log(filtered);
```

Answer (score 0):

`filter()` method creates a new array with all elements that pass the test implemented by the provided function.

```js
  var notUsed = ["Advanced Tac. Training Area", "Dunbarton Railroad Yard"];    
    var areas = ["A Area", "Advanced Tac. Training Area", "B Area", "Dunbarton Railroad Yard", "C Area"];    
    var out = areas.filter(function(index) {
     return notUsed.indexOf(index) == -1;
    });
    console.log(out);
```